# Click event not triggered

Tags: javascript

I followed this tutorial: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/26/expanding-search-bar-deconstructed/ to do an expanding search bar. But the javascript doesn't seem to be working.

**EDIT** Codepen of the problem : https://codepen.io/marinel2v/pen/Ljoyvz

Here's my markup :

```
<div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
    <form role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
        <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Rechercher un artiste, un événement, ..." type="search" value="" name="search" id="search" autocomplete="off">
        <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="">
        <span class="sb-icon-search"><?php get_template_part( 'svg/loupe' ); ?></span>
    </form>
</div>
```

As you can see I added `console.log('starting');` and `console.log('click');`

The first one is firing but not the second.

I don't understand why nothing happens when I click the search button...

```
;( function( window ) {

'use strict';
console.log('starting');

// EventListener | @jon_neal | //github.com/jonathantneal/EventListener
!window.addEventListener && window.Element && (function () {
   function addToPrototype(name, method) {
      Window.prototype[name] = HTMLDocument.prototype[name] = Element.prototype[name] = method;
   }

   var registry = [];

   addToPrototype("addEventListener", function (type, listener) {
      var target = this;

      registry.unshift({
         __listener: function (event) {
            event.currentTarget = target;
            event.pageX = event.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            event.pageY = event.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            event.preventDefault = function () { event.returnValue = false };
            event.relatedTarget = event.fromElement || null;
            event.stopPropagation = function () { event.cancelBubble = true };
            event.relatedTarget = event.fromElement || null;
            event.target = event.srcElement || target;
            event.timeStamp = +new Date;

            listener.call(target, event);
         },
         listener: listener,
         target: target,
         type: type
      });

      this.attachEvent("on" + type, registry[0].__listener);
   });

   addToPrototype("removeEventListener", function (type, listener) {
      for (var index = 0, length = registry.length; index < length; ++index) {
         if (registry[index].target == this && registry[index].type == type && registry[index].listener == listener) {
            return this.detachEvent("on" + type, registry.splice(index, 1)[0].__listener);
         }
      }
   });

   addToPrototype("dispatchEvent", function (eventObject) {
      try {
         return this.fireEvent("on" + eventObject.type, eventObject);
      } catch (error) {
         for (var index = 0, length = registry.length; index < length; ++index) {
            if (registry[index].target == this && registry[index].type == eventObject.type) {
               registry[index].call(this, eventObject);
            }
         }
      }
   });
})();

// http://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/989439
function mobilecheck() {
    var check = false;
    (function(a){if(/(android|ipad|playbook|silk|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
    return check;
}

// http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/polyfills-and-prototypes/
!String.prototype.trim && (String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
});

function UISearch( el, options ) {  
    this.el = el;
    this.inputEl = el.querySelector( 'form > input.sb-search-input' );
    this._initEvents();
}

UISearch.prototype = {
    _initEvents : function() {
        var self = this,
            initSearchFn = function( ev ) {
                console.log('click');
                ev.stopPropagation();
                // trim its value
                self.inputEl.value = self.inputEl.value.trim();

                if( !classie.has( self.el, 'sb-search-open' ) ) { // open it
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    self.open();
                }
                else if( classie.has( self.el, 'sb-search-open' ) && /^\s*$/.test( self.inputEl.value ) ) { // close it
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    self.close();
                }
            }

        this.el.addEventListener( 'click', initSearchFn );
        this.el.addEventListener( 'touchstart', initSearchFn );
        this.inputEl.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) { ev.stopPropagation(); });
        this.inputEl.addEventListener( 'touchstart', function( ev ) { ev.stopPropagation(); } );
    },
    open : function() {
        var self = this;
        classie.add( this.el, 'sb-search-open' );
        // focus the input
        if( !mobilecheck() ) {
            this.inputEl.focus();
        }
        // close the search input if body is clicked
        var bodyFn = function( ev ) {
            self.close();
            this.removeEventListener( 'click', bodyFn );
            this.removeEventListener( 'touchstart', bodyFn );
        };
        document.addEventListener( 'click', bodyFn );
        document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', bodyFn );
    },
    close : function() {
        this.inputEl.blur();
        classie.remove( this.el, 'sb-search-open' );
    }
}

// add to global namespace
window.UISearch = UISearch;

} )( window );
```

Comment: Could you share a codepen of this ? It would be much easier to help.

Comment: For sure ! I'll try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: https://codepen.io/marinel2v/pen/Ljoyvz here it is !

Comment: How do you instantiate uiSearch? Like this :  `new UISearch(document.querySelector('.sb-search-submit'))` ? I don't see this line!

Comment: Yes ! I forgot it ! I just added it as new UISearch( document.getElementById( 'sb-search' ) ); (i found it while checking the demo files). But now there's another problem. "Uncaught ReferenceError: classie is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.initSearchFn" which is weird because I included the classie.js file just at the beginning ?

Comment: could you update the codepen with the new error and indent your code for better readability ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the new error as it is directly linked to my Foundation install and probably is caused by me not linking the classie.js file correctly.
I ended up removing the classie.js file altogether as I am using jQuery which handles class really well. Thanks for the help !